# Forms authentication + URL Rewriting gives access to secure pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a problem with URL rewriting and Forms authentication in ASP.NET... Based on articles I've found on the net, I have created the following `HttpModule`:

```
public class UrlRewriter : IHttpModule
{
    private UrlRewriteConfigurationSection config;

    public UrlRewriter()
    {
        config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("urlrewrites") as UrlRewriteConfigurationSection;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        httpApplication.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(OnAuthorizeRequest);
    }

    private void OnAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string requestedPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

        foreach (UrlRewriteRule rule in config.UrlRewriteRules)
        {
            RegexOptions options = config.IgnoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None;

            Regex regex = new Regex(rule.UrlPattern, options);
            Match match = regex.Match(requestedPath);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                string newPath = regex.Replace(requestedPath, rule.RewritePattern);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newPath))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(newPath);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, however, is that this somehow disables authorization! To explain assume i have the following rewrite rule:

UrlPattern: `^user/profile$`
RewritePattern: `protected/profile.aspx`

And assume that the folder `protected` is setup to deny anonymous users access..

Now, when the code in the `OnAuthorizeRequest` runs, it correctly rewrites the path to `protected/profile.aspx`, however, the problem is that I am shown the page, even though I'm not logged in! If I request the page directly (http://localhost/site/protected/profile.aspx) it does not allow access to the site..

All articles I find on the net says I need to do the rewrite in `AuthorizeRequest` as opposed to `AuthenticateRequest` or `BeginRequest`..

Any ideas?

N.B.: I have tried moving my rewriting code to `AuthenticateRequest` which does seem to work, but redirection to the login page is not correct (e.g. it redirects to /login?returnUrl=protected/profile.aspx instead of login?returnUrl=user/profile)

Comment: Morten - this appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940067/using-forms-authentication-authorization-with-rewritten-urls

Comment: jro - You are right it is quite similar. However, the difference is that in your link, he solves the problem by adding .aspx to the "nice" url.. This does not work for me...